# NameError: name 'sequence' is not defined

Tags: arrays, sequence

I am using jupyter notebook.
i am trying to split the sequence into multiple samples.
running the following code gives me NameError.

```py
# univariate data preparation
from numpy import array

# split a univariate sequence into samples
def split_sequence(sequence, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(sequence)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)
    
# define input sequence
raw_seq = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
# choose a number of time steps
n_steps = 3
# split into samples
X, y = split_sequence(raw_seq, n_steps)
# summarize the data
for i in range(len(X)):
    print(X[i], y[i])
```

Comment: Please post your code with correct indentation.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17996/291426982.py in <module>
----> 1 for i in range(len(sequence)):
      2     # find the end of this pattern
      3     end_ix = i + n_steps
      4     # check if we are beyond the sequence
      5     if end_ix > len(sequence)-1:

NameError: name 'sequence' is not defined

Comment: I properly indented the question, try it out and I think it should work now.